# Which one is correct: I, I am, or me?

Tags: grammatical-case, objective-case

I am in a little bit confusion here. I was going through a blog article and I read

> He is more intelligent than **me**.

I think it is incorrect. It should have been

> He is more intelligent than **I am**.

To summarise, which is correct?

1. He is more intelligent than **me**
2. He is more intelligent than **I**
3. He is more intelligent than **I am**

Comment: Somebody taught you wrong. One can do whatever one pleases in this instance. Most people choose *than me*, which is perfectly grammatical. Please don't peeve.

Comment: @tchrist "... *than me*, which is perfectly grammatical:" some explanation of the grammar may be useful here.

Comment: Please visit [ell.se] -- I suggest this question be migrated there.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is an elliptical sentence that means

> He is more intelligent than I [am].

The subject of the dependent clause requires I.

There are some similar sentences where the objective case would work, but it changes the meaning.  For example,

> She likes her more than he.

means

> She likes her more than he likes her.

While a sentence such as

> She likes her more than him.

means

> She likes her more than she likes him.

Comment: You do have a point there, though that's unlikely to be what the present question is about.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit more on why you think my answer is unlikely to be what the present question is about.